# Laravel Passport and Shibboleth

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, shibboleth

I have a Laravel API using Passport.   All users login using Passport token based authentication.

I now have to adjust the API to support a NCAA university that uses Shibboleth SSO.   What would be the best way to seamlessly integrate this other authentication mechanism?  I'd need to add them as users in my users table because of how my client applications use the API.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I just found: https://packalyst.com/s/shibboleth